VSCODE cant remote to ALMA Linux Web Server
I successfully installed Alma Linux in VMWare with Web Server. I was able to use VSCode from my ROG Laptop connecting to my Alma Linux Web Server through SSH remote but The next morning my VSCode cannot anymore connect to my Alma Linux Web Server with the error below. Can Anybody help?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I was able to fix this by editing the %programdata%\ssh\sshd_config file in my local Windows Machine. Apparently, I accidentally inserted a line of code and messed it up. :) Hope this will help other people who did the same as I did. Thank you~
